# Getting a validation error on filtering inlines on Django Admin

Tags: python, django

There are an Invoice model and two Pricing models to calculate billing amount. I want detail pages of Invoice item on Django admin to show the only one inline determined by the attribute of Invoice model (`pricing_type`).

To achieve above, I wrote the code below but it raised an error(`django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']`) when I saved Invoice item on Django admin with the modified `pricing_type`. How can I make inlines on detail pages switchable?

#### Environment

- Django 2.0
- Python 3.6.3

#### models.py

```python
class Invoice(models.Model):
    pricing_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=(
            ('A', 'Pricing type A'),
            ('B', 'Pricing type B'),
        ),
        default='A')


class PricingA(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, models.CASCADE)


class PricingB(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, models.CASCADE)
```

#### admin.py

```python
class PricingAInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PricingA


class PricingBInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PricingB


@admin.register(Invoice)
class InvoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PricingAInline, PricingBInline]

    def get_formsets_with_inlines(self, request, obj=None):
        for inline in self.get_inline_instances(request, obj):
            if isinstance(inline, PricingAInline) and obj is not None and obj.pricing_type == 'A':
                yield inline.get_formset(request, obj), inline
            elif isinstance(inline, PricingBInline) and obj is not None and obj.pricing_type == 'B':
                yield inline.get_formset(request, obj), inline
            continue
```

Comment: how are you displaying your form? With formsets you need to also add the `managementform` in the template.

Comment: I'm using a default template([admin/edit_inline/tabular.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/edit_inline/tabular.html)). So I need to override it with adding `managementform`?

Comment: the default template already has `{{ inline_admin_formset.formset.management_form }}` defined, so you shouldn't have to override it. I would advise you to have a look at the HTML in your browser developer tools to see if each inline form has the hidden input for the management form; and check what's being posted. I don't have a clue right now.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to add a custom template and a custom tag for filtering inline contents in template level instead of `get_formsets_with_inlines()`. It works as I wanted.

#### MY_PROJECT/templates/admin/edit_inline/tabular.html

```
{% load i18n admin_urls static admin_modify %}
{% load customs %}
<div class="js-inline-admin-formset inline-group" id="{{ inline_admin_formset.formset.prefix }}-group"
     data-inline-type="tabular"
     data-inline-formset="{{ inline_admin_formset.inline_formset_data }}"
     {% visible_inline adminform.form.instance.pricing_type.class_name inline_admin_formset.opts.model %}>

...
```

#### MY_PROJECT/MY_APP/templatetags/customs.py

```python
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def visible_inline(class_name, inline):
    if class_name != inline.__class__.__name__:
        return mark_safe('style="display:none"')
```